# Support Vector Machine Optimization Problem,

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, optimization, linear-programming, machine-learning

The formulation of the SVM optimization problem is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& max_{w,b} \frac{1}{||w||} \\
& \text{ subject to } \\
& y_i(w^{T}x_i+b) \geq 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

What I do not understand is why do we use $w^Tx_i+b=1$ or $-1$ in the setup. My question is specifically about why 1? I understand that $w^Tx_i+b$ is the equation of a hyperplane and multiplying it by binary class labels $y_i \in \{-1,1\}$ we get the inequality but why do we initially not use $w^Tx_i+b = 2$ or 0 or any number. I am assuming we can adjust for this number since we have b as a hyperparameter.

Thank you!

P.S.:I doubt that this question was not asked before within another question but I cannot find it anywhere

Comment: It is not particularly important that the right hand side is one, but it **is** important that the right hand side is non-zero in order to induce a margin between the clusters. As you note, "we can adjust for this number". For instance, $w^Tx_i + b = 2$ is equivalent to $[\frac 12w]^Tx_i + \frac 12 b = 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Ben! Could you also explain why it needs to be non-zero as $w^Tx_i+b=2 <=> w^Tx_i + b' = 1$ where $b' = b-1$

Comment: @BenGrossmann also if you can post your answer to this question and your original answer as an answer, I will accept it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not particularly important that the right hand side is one, but it is important that the right hand side is bounded by two different numbers (such as $1$ and $-1$) in order to induce a margin between the clusters. As you note, "we can adjust for this number". For instance, $w^Tx_i + b = 2$ is equivalent to $[\frac 12 w]^T x_i + \frac 12 b = 1$ and to $w^Tx_i + (b - 1) = 1$.

Comment: I actually messed up my example, I wanted to say $w^Tx_i + b =1 <=> w^Tx_i+b'=0$ where $b'=b-1$. So, what I'm trying to ask is why the RHS has to be non-zero?

Comment: I was actually wrong about that. The important thing is that the lower bound for one cluster is larger than the upper bound for the other cluster; this is what induces the margin.